# Problem Compiling librocksdb-sys v6.11.4 on NEAR Protocol

Tags: rust, clang, blockchain, smartcontracts, nearprotocol

I am pretty new in the blockchain world and I am trying to implement the NFT example on NEAR protocol: https://github.com/near-examples/NFT. I am working on WSL (Ubuntu 20.04.3) installed in Windows 11. I already installed clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1.

When I run "./build.sh" everything seems to work ok, but when I test the contract with "cargo test -- --nocapture" the error below appears. Thanks in advance for your help.

````
warning: c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
warning: compilation terminated.

error: failed to run custom build command for `librocksdb-sys v6.11.4`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/mnt/c/Users/Joluc/documents/jorge/near/demo/nft/target/debug/build/librocksdb-sys-eaafd69bcf3ae43c/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-changed=rocksdb/
  TARGET = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  HOST = Some("x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu")
  CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CXX = None
  CXX = None
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
  CXXFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("true")
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CXX = None
  CXX = None
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
  CXXFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CXX = None
  CXX = None
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
  CXXFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CXX = None
  CXX = None
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
  CXXFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  CXX_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CXX_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CXX = None
  CXX = None
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu = None
  CXXFLAGS_x86_64_unknown_linux_gnu = None
  HOST_CXXFLAGS = None
  CXXFLAGS = None
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("fxsr,sse,sse2")
  running: "c++" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-I" "rocksdb/include/" "-I" "rocksdb/" "-I" "rocksdb/third-party/gtest-1.8.1/fused-src/" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "lz4/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/" "-I" "zstd/lib/dictBuilder/" "-I" "zlib/" "-I" "bzip2/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c++11" "-Wno-unused-parameter" "-msse2" "-msse4.1" "-msse4.2" "-mpclmul" "-DSNAPPY=1" "-DLZ4=1" "-DZSTD=1" "-DZLIB=1" "-DBZIP2=1" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-DHAVE_SSE42=1" "-DHAVE_PCLMUL=1" "-DOS_LINUX=1" "-DROCKSDB_PLATFORM_POSIX=1" "-DROCKSDB_LIB_IO_POSIX=1" "-o" "/mnt/c/Users/Joluc/documents/jorge/near/demo/nft/target/debug/build/librocksdb-sys-a0ba192c69e01297/out/rocksdb/db/arena_wrapped_db_iter.o" "-c" "rocksdb/db/arena_wrapped_db_iter.cc" ```
````

Comment: Does Task Manager (outside WSL) or `top` (inside WSL) show anything suspicious, such as a spike in memory usage?

Comment: I hadn't noticed it before but yes, a new process named 'Vmmem' showed up and it uses 2,2 GB aprox in memory and a good portion of the CPU capacity. Additionally, the memory usage does'nt decrease even after the error appears and the process stops.